# Java array contains turns up false, how to check array contains

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, contains

I have a set stored in shared preferences and another array that is pulled from a database. When I convert the set to array and compare if the array contains the array from the database, it shows nothing. I have printed the results from each array to the console separately and my values are spot on. Any ideas why this won't work?

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("User", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final Set<String> greenSet = prefs.getStringSet("greenIngredients", null);

//pulls data_ingredients from database as a string, converts to array

String[] ingredientResult = data_ingredients.split(", ");
int val = ingredientResult.length;

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.greenLL);
final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[val]; // create an empty array;


    String[] greenArray = greenSet.toArray(new String[greenSet.size()]);
    if (!(greenSet ==null)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < val; i++) {
            final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
            rowTextView.setText(ingredientResult[i]);

            if(Arrays.asList(greenArray).contains(ingredientResult[i])){
            System.out.println("yes");
        }

            // add the textview to the linearlayout
            ll.addView(rowTextView);

            // save a reference to the textview for later
            myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
        }
    }
```

Also, just as a side note, this is happening in a loop which is dynamically generates a textview for each item that exists in the array pulled from the database.

variable greenSet is actually a dynamically generated set, but is just a set of items populated from another part of the application. In this instance, console prints greenSet as

```
I/System.out: [Beefeater Gin, ]
```

and ingredientResult as

```
I/System.out: [Beefeater Gin, 1 Scoop Pistachio Ice Cream, Root Beer]
```

Comment: You print `greenSet` but what about printing `greenArray` as a List, which is what you are comparing to `ingredientResult[i]`?

Comment: This comment actually helped me quite a bit. I was comparing Arrays.asList. Instead I changed Arrays.asList to Arrays.toString and it worked. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I changed 
    Arrays.asList 
to 
    Arrays.toString
in my if statement.